# TS error are not highlighted in Intellij after eslint is installed

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have tsconfig.json and that works fine, IntelliJ shows the erros. But when I install eslint, ts highlits just dissappeears. I do not understand why?

```
env:
  es2021: true
  node: true

extends:
  - eslint:all
  - plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended
  - plugin:import/recommended
  - plugin:import/typescript
  - plugin:node/recommended
  - plugin:security/recommended
  - plugin:sonarjs/recommended
  - plugin:yml/standard

ignorePatterns:
  - output/

parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser'

parserOptions:
  ecmaVersion: latest
  sourceType: script

plugins:
  - '@typescript-eslint'
  - import
  - no-floating-promise
  - node
  - security
  - sonarjs
  - yml
```

tsconfig:

```
"compilerOptions": {
"allowJs": true,
"checkJs": true,
"module": "NodeNext",
"noEmit": true,
"noImplicitAny": false,
"resolveJsonModule": true
```

},

Thanks

I would like to see both eslint and ts errors to be highlighted in IntelliJ.

Comment: It works for me in 2023.2. Both TS and ESLint errors are shown. Please provide a code sample where you don't get TypeScript errors and your package.json.

Answer (score 0):

In my case [this answer](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/1848#issuecomment-613313431) helped me. Just try closing the IDE, deleting the `.idea` directory and starting the IDE again.

Comment: Warning! If you delete your project .idea folder, you might face some unexpected issues. Like your Shelf history will be deleted. Also, that didn't fix the issue for me.